# Opencart, разные валюты в админке и фронте

Tags: php, opencart

В админке по умолчанию выбрана валюта `USD`, и в настройках локализации выбрано значение для доллара `1.00000000`.
Также в настройках локализации есть валюта UAH со значением `28.00000000`.
Как сделать, чтобы во фронтенде была другая валюта, допустим грн?
Выбор валюты в шапке отключён, т.к. предусматривается на сайте только одна валюта: грн, а в админке товарам цены будут назначаться в уе

**P.S.**
нашёл код в инете, там нужно вставить участок кода в файле 
`catalog/controller/startup/startup.php` после этой строки,
`$this->registry->set('currency', new Cart\Currency($this->registry));`
но этот код для старой версии `opencart`
`$registry->get('currency')->set('UAH');`
подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Есть ли идеи как это сделать?

Comment: У вас какая версия OpenCart?

Comment: Версия Ocstore 2.3.0.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле catalog/controller/startup/startup.php перед строкой

```
$this->registry->set('currency', new Cart\Currency($this->registry));
```

добавьте

```
$this->session->data['currency'] = 'UAH';
```

Еще, как вариант, можно попробовать в файле system/library/cart/currency.php заменить

```
public function format($number, $currency, $value = '', $format = true) {
```

на

```
public function format($number, $currency = 'UAH', $value = '', $format = true) {
```

И не забывайте, при правках, про системный кэш и кэш модификаторов. Ну и про куки/кэш браузера.

Answer (score 1):

Делал сегодня эту задачу.
ocStore 2.3.0.2.2
В базе хранится в $, в админке вывод в $ и гривнах.
Прикладываю скрины коммита.
Вдохновили ответы выше, спасибо их авторам.
[image: screen_1]

[image: screen_2]

[image: screen_3]

Comment: Код приложите текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: В таком виде (код картинкой, а не текстом) читать крайне сложно. Будет гораздо полезнее, если Вы доработаете ответ.